# Showing that function for IF statement does not work the same way as IF statement

Tags: python-3.x

This is a question for a homework problem that I cant figure out:

***Question Beginning***

Q3. Let's try to write a function that does the same thing as an if statement:

```
def if_function(condition, true_result, false_result):

    """Return true_result if condition is a true value, and false_result otherwise."""

    if condition:
        return true_result
    else:
        return false_result
```

This function actually doesn't do the same thing as an if statement in all cases. To prove this fact, write functions c, t, and f such that one of these functions returns the number 1, but the other does not:

```
def with_if_statement():

    if c():
        return t()
    else:
        return f()

def with_if_function():

    return if_function(c(), t(), f())
```

***Question End***

Heres what I figured out:

with_if_statement() does not evaluate f() if c() is true, but with_if_function() evaluates all 3 before checking if c() is true or not.

So, I thought of assigning a global variable in c(), and changing its value in f()

heres my code (which does not work):

```
def c():

    try:
        global x
    except NameError:
        x=1
    if x==1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def t():

    if x==1:
        return (1)
    else:
        return (0)

def f():

    global x
    x=2
    if x==1:
        return (1)
    else:
        return (0)
```

can anyone help me figure out the answer? Thanks..!

Comment: I've fixed your formatting. Indent code by four spaces (Ctrl+K or the corresponding toolbar button). The `<code>` tag is an inline tag as per HTML, you don't need to use it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `global` statement shouldn't throw a `NameError` (and so you won't run `x=1` in `c()`). I would try rewriting your code *without* using exceptions, they won't be necessary to solve this and are making it more complicated than it needs to be. Using a global variable and having side effects in your functions is certainly the right track.

Comment: In both with_if_statement() and with_if_function() c() is called first. So, c() has to assign something to x.

Then, I want to change value of x in f(), and not let it be changed again when c() is called. How do I do that?

Comment: Well, in `c()` you could compare the value of `x` with 2 (the value assigned in `f()`).

Comment: But I get error: global variable x not defined for thsi code:

def c():
    global x
    if x!=2:
        x=1
    if x==1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

Also, I still dont get how code formatting works on stack overflow...

Comment: Using the `global x` statement does not *create* a global variable. It simply provides *access* to a global variable within a function, so that when you assign to it the assignment goes to the global variable and not to a new local variable. The problem with the code in the previous comment is if you don't assign `x=1`, then `x` still doesn't exist when you compare it with `x==1`. An easy way to solve this is to stick `x = 0` at the top of your script, then it will always exist.

Comment: Well, in the question, I am only allowed to change functions c(), t(), and f(); nothing else, so how do I assign x=0 at beginning?
I guess what I am looking for is an "isset()" type function (as in php). Googling that, I found that try does the same. But that does not work, and hence I dont know what to do. I am sure I am just overcomplicating things. I just need as easy way  to make a global variable x in c(), assign it a value only if its not been assigned a value (in c()), make c() return true if x = 1 and false otherwise, and then change its value in f() so that c() returns false..but how?

Comment: I told you how. Put `x = 0` at the top of your script. Continue to use `global x`. Don't use exceptions.

Comment: Well, in the question, I am only allowed to change functions c(), t(), and f(); nothing else....

Comment: I don't see where your question says that you can't set up a global variable like that.

Comment: got it. without having to use IF:

def c():
    global x
    x=0
    return False
def t():
    global x
    x=x+1
    return (x)
def f():
    global x
    x=x+1
    return (x)

Thanks...especially for the last line...coz I re read the question... and understood how to do it without using IF statements...!

Answer (score 2):

```
def if_function(condition, true_result, false_result):
    """Return true_result if condition is a true value, and
    false_result otherwise.

    >>> if_function(True, 2, 3)
    2
    >>> if_function(False, 2, 3)
    3
    >>> if_function(3==2, 3+2, 3-2)
    1
    >>> if_function(3>2, 3+2, 3-2)
    5
    """
    if condition:
        return true_result
    else:
        return false_result


def with_if_statement():
    """
    >>> with_if_statement()
    1
    """
    if c():
        return t()
    else:
        return f()

def with_if_function():
    return if_function(c(), t(), f())
```

The question requires that, write 3 functions: `c`, `t` and `f` such that `with_if_statement` returns `1` and `with_if_function` does not return 1 (and it can do anything else)

At the beginning, the problem seems to be ridiculous since, logically, `with_if_statement` and `with_if_function` are same. However, if we see these two functions from an interpreter view, they are different.

The function `with_if_function` uses a call expression, which guarantees that all of its operand subexpressions will be evaluated before `if_function` is applied to the resulting arguments. Therefore, even if `c` returns `False`, the function `t` will be called. By contrast, `with_if_statement` will never call `t` if `c` returns False (This paragraph from the UCB website).

```
def c():
    return True

def t():
    return 1

def f():
    '1'.sort() # anything breaks the program is OK
```